# Which Vector Space is connected

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology

Let $V$ be span of $(1,1,1) $ and $(0,1,1) \in \mathbb{R^3}.$ Let $u_1=(0,0,1), u_2=(1,1,0)$ and $u_3=(1,0,1).$ Which of the following are correct?

1. $(\mathbb{R^3} \setminus V) \cup ({0,0,0})$ is not connected.
2. $(\mathbb{R^3} \setminus V) \cup (\{tu_1+(1-t)u_3: 0 \leq t \leq 1\}$ is not connected.
3. $(\mathbb{R^3} \setminus V) \cup \{tu_1+(1-t)u_3: 0 \leq t \leq 1\}$ is connected.
4. $(\mathbb{R^3} \setminus V) \cup \{(t,2t,2t): t \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is connected.

It seems intutively to me that 1 is not correct  as $(\mathbb{R^3} \setminus V) \cup ({0,0,0})$ is connected.

but how to approach other options. Can someone give a clear picture of options with the help of visual image or graph. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: What do you mean by $R^3/V$ here?

Comment: I think the vectors in $\mathbb{R^3}$ which are not in $V$

Comment: $R^3/V$ all the vectors of R^3 except those in $V$

Comment: The notation for that would be $\Bbb R^3\setminus V$.

Answer (score 2):

A space is disconnected if it can be broken into 2 disjoint open sets.
A space is connected if it cannot.

1) is connected
$(0,0,0)$ is a limit point of $\mathbb R^3 \setminus V$

2,3) $t u_1 + (1-t)u_3 = (1-t, 0,0)$ which is a vector in $V.$

$\mathbb R^3 \setminus V \cup (\{(1-t, 0,0)|0≤t≤1\})$ is a union of disjoint sets.

Similarly for 4, $(t,2t,2t)$ is in V
and the sets are not connected.

Comment: Sir if i am not wrong then isn't 4th is connected as  $(t,2t,2t)$ is not in $V$

Comment: It isn't?  $(1,1,1) t+ (0,1,1)t = (t,2t,2t)$